# Has anyone considered an Evolution Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Google and Facebook have figured out that I like seeing the latest palaeontological announcements, so I'm always seeing headlines like [this one](https://www.livescience.com/64642-antarctic-king-ancient-lizard.html) on an early Triassic lizard.

This always spurs me to poke around the net about some facet of the article.  For this one, I looked up "Early Triassic" to get a sense of what that meant.  I ended up on [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Triassic#/media/File:Triassic_marine_vertebrate_apex_predators.png) of marine life at the time.  I noticed some disk shaped fish that looked, to me, like Permit or a Sunny.

I wondered, "What ecological niche are disk shaped fish exploiting?  Why is this particular body type - or any body type for that matter - repeating itself 250 million years later".

I'd like to ask this of a Stack Exchange forum.  So, is there a particular reason there isn't an Evolution forum?

Comment: There isn't because nobody proposed it, or at least not successfully. New sites are created as result of someone starting the process on Area 51, see more details in the dupe.

Comment: I was not asking how to propose a a new site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Biology site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) it has an [evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution) [tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) with the following description

> Changes in the heritable attributes of populations of organisms over time. The mechanisms of evolution are mutation, migration, drift, and selection.

That seems to be along the right lines for your question. As always check the site's [help centre](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more information